# SMTP traffic forward/relay?

Tags: c#

We have three different networks. Regular, Trusted, Secure. Regular has access to the internet and trusted. Trusted has access to regular, internet and Secure. Secure has access to Trusted.

We used to have a local SMTP server but the powers that be decided to move it, externally. Now the secure network does not have access to it.

For my own home grown code that runs in secure I have written a .Net Web service to send email. This works great.

The problem is that we cannot modify canned applications the best we can do is change the server address and the port of the SMTP server.

I set out to write my own SMTP server that basically forwards the message to the external SMTP server. Probably easy enough but it will take some time.

I am hoping someone out there knows of a solution that we can purchase or another way of doing what we need.

Comment: Why can't you use the address and port for the external SMTP server?

Comment: The machine that I want to use the SMTP server from does not have access to that network. Although it has access to a network which has access to the SMTP server.

Comment: You just need a normal SMTP server and configure it as a smarthost or relay, windows server comes with one and there are plenty for *nix...  But you need to speak to your security people about how to properly install, secure and firewall it so that it's only able to communicate what it should to who it should.